# Glob returns back an empty list in Python

Tags: python, regex, glob

My code:

```
hi = glob.glob("hi/FEC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9].seq")
```

I'm using a glob module and I'm trying to get all the path file names but all it returns back is a empty list. I don't know why it keeps doing that. It worked before my code was accidentally erased.

```
[]
```

Regardless if the file isn't even there, it still gives me an empty list.

Update:
So the following files I have are

FEC00001_1.seq

FEC00002_1.seq

FEC00002_2.seq

and so on..

Update 2:
So it I just realized that it might have to do something with the wrong folder like you guys said.

Because right now, my script is in "folder1" and all the files I'm trying to access is in "folder2"

/mainfolder/folder1/script.py

/mainfolder/folder2/*files im trying to access*

Comment: Please let us know which types of filename you are trying to match so that we may verify your regular expression syntax.

Comment: Even if the regex syntax is wrong, it doesn't give me any errors, it still gives me an empty list

Comment: The reason why it returned an empty list is because none of the file name matches your pattern. So please check your file paths.

Comment: Can you try opening one of your files: `fo = open("FEC00001_1.seq", "r") print "filename: ", fo.name` ?

Comment: What could also happen is that the working folder is not the one you think it is. Maybe could you add print os.getcwd()

Comment: Try `os.listdir('hi')`, and `os.getcwd()`, to work out where it's looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob.glob` is done by using the `os.listdir()` and `fnmatch.fnmatch()` functions in concert. So it's important that you search at the right place. 
Considering your file hierarchy:-

```
/mainfolder/folder1/script.py
/mainfolder/folder2/files im trying to access
```

try the following :-

hi = glob.glob("../folder2/FEC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9].seq")

Comment: Thank you so much! It was a folder hierarchy issue

Comment: @David can you upvote and accept the answer if this solves your problem. Will help both of us with some repo. :)